# Multivariate mixture models

Tags: clustering, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, model-based-clustering

I am new to mixture modeling and have successfully used bernoulli mixture models to cluster datasets of binary data.

My real purpose, though is to cluster datasets with mixed data types: normal, multinomial, binary, poisson. If I treat the columns independently does it make sense to train a mixture model where each component is comprised of these different distributions as well?

For example, the mtcars dataset that ships with R. Could I specify a different distribution for each element of the components depending on the column?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first thing to consider is a dataset with all columns being of normal distributions. Here the multivariate normal distribution is used to identify clusters, where the covariance structure is used to identify patterns between columns. This gives rise to a model that accounts for all parameter estimates across columns.

Likewise to integrate a normal, multinomial, binary, poisson a similar approach to combining and integrating parameters learned from the distributions would be important...